# Can't use <filesystem> in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use filesystem, but it doesn't work in VS19. Even with /std:c++17. Any ideas why? Maybe I have to install some special packages?

[image]

Edit. Compilation error:

[image]

Edit 2.  header:

[image]

Comment: Does this code compile? IntelliSense errors in some cases don't correlate with real compilation ones.

Comment: @Evg, no it doesn't. Check the edit.

Comment: Your code worked for me in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.3 after I enabled c++17 on all configurations of a console application in x64 mode.

Comment: @drescherjm, you really helped. For some reason I had to switch all the projects in the solution to /std:c++17 in order to make this work, not only the one with this code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you apply the `/std:c++17` setting to all configurations. The default behavior of changing project properties only updates the active configuration. In my brief testing I had the Intellisense error with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.3 until I made this switch.